# Check whether the following expressions are equivalent

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$(x-1)(x^{n+1}-1)=(x^2-2x+1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+x+1)$$
Are the following expressions listed above equivalent? If they are, how to show that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints**: you can verify via direction multiplication of the RHS's below that
$$
(x-1)^2=(x^2-2x+1),\\
(x^{n+1}-1)=(x-1)(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+1).
$$
Once you have done that, you can see that both sides of the your original (supposed) equality can be written as
$$
(x-1)^2(x^n+x^{n-1}+\cdots+1).
$$

Comment: Not really, more details please.

Comment: @Kim Jong Un You got the binomial in that hint wrong bro.

Comment: @kazinsky See my edit.@ GDumphart: thanks. I fixed it.

Comment: I've finally got this! Thank you

Comment: @kazinsky You're welcome. Don't forget to accept useful answers to mark your questions as resolved.